# Error: X does not name a type

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this code:

```
class C {
  public:
  int h();
};

C he;          //Fine
he.h();        //Error: 'he' does not name a type

int main() {
  C me;           //Fine
  me.h();         //Fine
}
```

Using MinGW 4.6.2.

***Note***: I am only compiling, not linking.

Comment: Why would `main` exist if you could call functions outside of it?

Comment: The errors you get at compilation are compilation errors(a.k.a: errors because your code does not follow rules laid out by the language). What you get at runtime are runtime exceptions(a.k.a: your code follows language rules but does things that might go wrong at execution time).

Comment: I was thing why can I do 'int i', but cannot do the same with the class. I just realized that I can declare a class, not execute its functions.

Comment: @Pubby: In C++ you *can* call functions "outside of `main`". Function calls can be issued from constructors of global objects, from initializer expressions etc. There are quite a few dangerous pitfalls in that, but the possibility is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the uppermost level, each C++ translation unit must consist of declarations

```
translation-unit: 
  declaration-seq[opt]

declaration-seq:
  declaration
  declaration-seq declaration
```

Bur `he.h();` is not a declaration. Hence the error.

You can introduce a dummy variable to turn it into a declaration

```
int dummy = he.h();
```

and the code will compile. But the original version is illegal.

Answer (score 6):

Outside a function, you can only put declarations/definitions. To just execute something like `he.h();`, that code needs to go in a function.